# Post body not received

Tags: php, curl, post, request

My curl post doesn't return a body on the server side. How can I rectify this?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$cpUrl);// "ex:www.lalala/aa/"
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $varpost); // has string parameter
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('VariableParams:'.$varpost ));
info ("variables passed:",$varpost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
$output = curl_exec ($ch); // Execute
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen that for the server the request is redirected into another url. For example based on location some website redirects it to a particular location. That's why you are not getting any body as you are disabling the follow location option.

Try by enabling it.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```